# 4xx pages template override

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to implement the solution given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139541/custom-404-template-file-in-drupal-8/43421614#43421614).

I want to have custom templates for 4xx pages.

I am using Drupal 8.3.1

I have tried the code as given in the above link to create the page suggestions in my theme's `.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page() to set 40x template suggestions
 */
function MY_THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page(array $variables) {
  $path_args = explode('/', trim(\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath(), '/'));
  $suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page');
  $http_error_suggestions = [
    'system.401' => 'page__401',
    'system.403' => 'page__403',
    'system.404' => 'page__404',
  ];
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if (isset($http_error_suggestions[$route_name])) {
    $suggestions[] = $http_error_suggestions[$route_name];
  }

  return $suggestions;
}
```

It does not appear to work.

`page--404.html.twig` or `page--system--404.html.twig` are not being used.

404 and 403 pages are not set inside the admin of the page.

What else am I suppose to do to get this working?

Comment: I am getting ready to do something similar and was researching this, and I see folks using HOOK_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x so, I wonder if you just need to add _alter to your function name.  Also, it's always worth mentioning, did you 'clear all caches' under admin->config->devel->performance?

Comment: Sure have, many times. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the same code as you have with the exception that I have a `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter()`. With the `_alter` attached to it.

Try putting the HOOK in a custom module instead of the `.theme` file.